# SQL create a DateTime value from Year and Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know the year and the quarter (e.g. "2010" and "4") for a schedule-related milestone and I want to select/create a datetime from it.  There are a number of nifty ways to identify the quarter with formats ("qq") of a particular date, but not to go the other way around (or are there?).  This is with t-sql / SQL Server.

Note: the datetime should be for the **last** day of that quarter.

**UPDATE: Here is the solution that I ended up using courtesy of gbn, with AaronLS's variable names and then shortened-and-sweetened with Frank Kalis' suggestion :-)  It was important to test for all 4 quarters to make sure the year is handled properly.  Thanks to everyone who answered!**

```
DECLARE @TheQuarter INT
DECLARE @theYear INT
-- Note: qq = q = quarter for the datepart
SET @TheQuarter = 1
SET @TheYear = 2011
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @TheYear-1900, DATEADD(qq, @TheQuarter, -1))
-- 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000

SET @TheQuarter = 2
SET @TheYear = 2011
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @TheYear-1900, DATEADD(qq, @TheQuarter, -1))
-- 2011-06-30 00:00:00.000

SET @TheQuarter = 3
SET @TheYear = 2011
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @TheYear-1900, DATEADD(qq, @TheQuarter, -1))
-- 2011-09-30 00:00:00.000

SET @TheQuarter = 4
SET @TheYear = 2011
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @TheYear-1900, DATEADD(qq, @TheQuarter, -1))
-- 2011-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Here are a few q's that fetch the quarter from the date but not the other way around:
[Calculate the Last Day in the CURRENT quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615778/calculate-the-last-day-in-the-current-quarter); [Calculate the last day of the quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302452/calculate-the-last-day-of-the-quarter); [Best way to store quarter and year in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709247/best-way-to-store-quarter-and-year-in-sql-server)

Comment: You've included links to other SO questions - do these not answer _your question_?

Comment: These don't answer my question, but were helpful towards the understanding of how SQL server deals with qq/quarter.

Comment: mellamokb's answer, or a close variant thereof, should be what you're after.

Comment: Some of the proposed solutions below work properly for Q1, Q2 and Q3 but show the incorrect YEAR for Q4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never use strings for datetime conversions: too much to go wrong with formats, language etc.

Keep it in the datetime type...

```
Select dateadd(day, -1, 
                       dateadd(year, @year-1900,
                                          dateadd(quarter, @qq, 0)
                                     )
             )
```

Comment: This works for all Quarters in a given year: SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, @TheYear-1900, DATEADD(qq, @TheQuarter, 0)))
yields the correct "2011-12-31 00:00:00.000" - short and sweet, too!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you've already found your solution, but just for the sake of it...
If you choose a different base date, you can shorten the whole thing to

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @TheYear-1900, DATEADD(qq, @TheQuarter, -1))
```

Since 0 indicates SQL Server's base date of 01.01.1900 (and the first day of a month), using -1 as base date starts off 1 day earlier and then you already have your last day of a month (and end of a quarter). Then you just need to do the rest of the datetime magic and voilà.

Comment: +1 for explaining the background info on date handling and making it even shorter!

Comment: Yes very succinct.  I like it too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns
    9/30/2014 12:00:00 AM
The actual quarter DateTime should be
    9/30/2014 23:59:59 PM

Answer (score 2):

Just choose the date from the quarter:

```
select
    case @theQuarter
        when 1 then '3/31/' + cast(@theYear as varchar(4))
        when 2 then '6/30/' + cast(@theYear as varchar(4))
        when 3 then '9/30/' + cast(@theYear as varchar(4))
        when 4 then '12/31/' + cast(@theYear as varchar(4))
    end as quarterDate
```

**Edit**: Adjusted to be last day of quarter instead of first day.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't handle if the "end of the year" is shifted as is frequently the case in Fiscal Years for companies. @AaronLS's solution is slightly better as you can then add a calculation to handle this shift by taking the Calendar Year End and subtract the Fiscal Year End.

Answer (score 1):

This basically gets the first day of the following quarter, and then subtracts one so that you have the last day of the quarter you wanted.  `(@theQuarter + 1)` adds one to the quarter, then `*3 -2` gets the first month of that quarter, and `% 12` is required when for the fourth quarter because you add one to 4 to get 5, which gives you 13 but you really want 1, so the % takes care of that.

Finally after casting it all to a date time, we have the first day of the following quarter, thus subtract `- 1` at the end to subtract one day and get the last day of the quarter we initially put in.

```
declare @theQuarter as int;
set @theQuarter = 4;

declare @theYear as int;
set @theYear = 2009;

select 
cast(
  cast(
        ( (@theQuarter + 1) * 3 - 2) % 12 
  as varchar(2)) 
  + '-01-' 
  + cast( (@theYear + (((@theQuarter + 1) * 3 - 2)/ 12) ) as varchar(4))  
as datetime) - 1 ;
```

Comment: This gives "2008-12-31 00:00:00.000" as a result -- off by a year for Q4... Q1->Q3 work OK.

Comment: @Mark good catch.  I have fixed that bug now and edited the code in the post.